# Jenkins freestyle job running selectively downstream jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I searched many places. Cannot find proper help.
I have job A calling downstream jobs w,x,y,z
I can use Extended Choice Parameter plugin , so user can select few from the list of w,x,y,z.
I should be able to run selectively these jobs.

Example, user chooses w,x. Run only those. skip y and z.

Comment: Why there is -1 for this question?

Answer (score 0):

How about use jenkins pipeline? Extended Choice Parameter plugin also support pipeline script

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately cannot use Jenkins pipeline. It has to be freestyle.